# Unable to see the time a chat message was posted to the second without starring it

Tags: feature-request, chat

The mouseover tooltip behaivor is different for the "#h/#m ago" in the menu brought up by clicking the arrow on the left of a chat message:

[image: imprecise time]

versus the one on a starred message

[image: down to the second]

Can the tooltip for the former be just like the latter?

Comment: there's an stackapp for that: http://stackapps.com/questions/2105/se-chat-modifications-keyboard-navigation-and-commands-for-chat